# How to use struct array in a function as a parameter in C?

Tags: arrays, c, parameters, casting, linked-list

I am trying to fill an array with linkedlist nodes.But I get some errors.

- List struct
- fillArray method

```
struct List
{
    char frequency[STRING_LEN];
    char word[STRING_LEN];
    char lineOrder[STRING_LEN];
    struct List *next;
};

void fillArray(struct List *nodesArr[50]){
     int a=0;
    struct List *ptr = head;  // head is my first node for linkedlist. I have created this earlier.
    
    while(ptr->next!=NULL){
        
        *nodesArr[a]->frequency=ptr->frequency; // I get error here
        *nodesArr[a]->word=ptr->word; //  and here  *assignment to 'char' from 'char *' makes integer from* //*pointer without a cast*

        ptr=ptr->next;
        a++;


    }
}

*assignment to 'char' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]gcc* error
[error][1]
[error2][1]
```

Also I am declaring nodesArr in main func like this:

```
struct List *nodesArr[length()];
```

I am calling fillArray method like this:

```
 fillArray(*nodesArr); // How should I put an array as a parameter?
```

I don't know how to use struct array as a parameter in a function and what to do to get away from casting error.
Any help would be appreciated
*Thanks in advance*

Edit
I have transformed fillArray method like this to be more clear.

```
void fillArray(struct List **nodesArr){
     int a=0;
    struct List *ptr = head;
    
    while(ptr->next!=NULL){
       
        
        strcpy(nodesArr[a]->frequency,ptr->frequency);
        strcpy(nodesArr[a]->word,ptr->word);

        ptr=ptr->next;
        a++;


    }
}
```

edit2
head is defined global

```
struct List *head = NULL;
```

I fill head linkedlist with this method:

```
void insertFirst(char *data, char *frequency, char *lineOrder)
{
    struct List *link = (struct List *)malloc(sizeof(struct List));
    strcpy(link->word, data); // To copy the elements of data to new node's word
    strcpy(link->frequency, frequency);
    strcpy(link->lineOrder, lineOrder);
    link->next = head;
    head = link;
}
```

Comment: Please update the question with the exact errors.

Comment: `struct List *nodesArr[50]` is an array of 50 **pointers** to `struct List`

Comment: 1-assignment to 'char' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]gcc
2-passing argument 1 of 'printArray' from incompatible pointer type

Comment: `char frequency[STRING_LEN];` and `char word[STRING_LEN];` are **arrays** and cannot be **lvalues**. Your types look completely wrong for what you explain you want to accomplish. If you just want an array of struct see [C Source #2 Example on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/6s3fjn) otherwise, please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you for your update, but it isn't a MCVE. For instance, what is `head` in `struct List *ptr = head;` and how it is declared and initialized before your first call to `fillArray()`? If it is initialized `NULL`, you will SegFault at `ptr=ptr->next;`

Answer (score 1):

The confusion that your running into is due to the fact that arrays are not first-class types in C, and there are a lot of things you can't do with them.  In particular:

- You can't declare a function parameter as an array.  If you do, the compiler will silently turn it into a pointer with no warning or error.  This is a frequent source of confusion for programmers new to C.  In your case, when you declare `fillArray(struct List *nodesArr[50])` it is as if you declared `fillArray(struct List **nodesArr)`
- You can't pass an array as a parameter.  If you do so, it will silently be converted into a pointer to the array's first (0th) element.

Now the above silent conversions may seem odd, but they usually work out, as array indexing is silenty converted to pointer arithmetic under the hood, so as far as most uses are concerned, you use a pointer to an array's first element the same way you would use the array.  So within the function, you can use the double pointer as if it was an array of pointers and things will work out.  The only real fly in the ointment is that `sizeof` does not work properly -- it gives the size of the pointer rather than the size of the array.

Comment: It does exactly what you say, it points to 0th element and nothing more.So I think ,I need to find a away without using this as a parameter to fill an array with nodes. Am I wrong?
Thank you